# How to access a method from pytest, if there's no explicit root package or module

Tags: python, pytest

Simply speaking, I have this directory structure:

```
src/
  my_file1.py

tests/
  __init__.py
  my_file1_test.py
```

In  `my_file1.py`:

```
def my_func1(a):
  return a + 99
```

How do I then access my_func1 from the tests? In my_file1_test.py I can't access the method:

```
# from ??? import ?? # is this needed at all?

def my_test1():
  res = my_func1(123) # unaccessible
  assert res = 222
```

Will I have to create `__init__.py` in `scr` directory first?

**update1**

```
from src.myfile import my_func1
```

===>

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scr'
```

And if I add `__init__.py` then it'll become:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'my_func1' from 'src'
```

Comment: What python version are you running and are you running the command in project root?

Comment: @Tzane I've maked it as "solved". Check out my other question now please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69556855/a-pytest-cant-find-a-module-in-a-file-whereas-running-that-file-directly-via

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run pytest from your project root with

`python -m pytest`

you then have to import the function, as you guessed, with:

`from src.myfile import my_func1`

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scr'`